# Why Adam wasn’t explicitly commanded to pass his knowledge on to others?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mitzvah, theology, adam

I'm still trying to grasp the way of transmission of the Torah knowledge from day 1. This question can equally deal with two phenomena: the commandment of eating the forbidden fruit or the commandment of the 7 Laws.

IIRC (please correct me if I'm mistaken):

1. G-d creates Adam
2. G-d commands Adam not to eat the fruit and (independently) keep the 7 Laws
3. It is clear that G-d expects all humans to observe the commandments given to Adam.
4. G-d doesn't command Adam to pass it on to other humans, his wife or sons or descendants.
5. G-d harshly judges Eve and Adam's descendants for not keeping the commandments.

The necessity of passing the commandments is absolutely crucial for the justification of G-d's judgment both for Eve eating the fruit or Kain killing Abel.

This is true for all following generations that could claim that though Adam was commanded, he didn't bother teaching the future generations, just as he didn't bother to teach his own wife.

Why didn't G-d care to command Adam (and following generations) on passing the original Law on?

Comment: @ Al Berko, could you clarify in b. "and/or"?

Comment: @gamliela I edited. THe question refers to the two examples of commandments that were eventually transgressed

Comment: Where are you getting number 3 from? We know that Eve did know about some prohibition, she says it explicitly in the Torah to the snake (albeit an inaccurately restrictive prohibition). Clearly, Adam did convey some sort of prohibition to her.

Comment: Initially the commandment to not eat this one fruit was the only one. So to utterly obey G-d was enough. they were completely in safety until they failed in the original commandment.

Comment: @Al Berko Even though the Torah was before this though, Adam and Eve evidently weren't told. Things had to unfold in a certain way according to G-d's creation

Comment: Let’s say they did pass down commandments. How does that justify punishing future generations?

Comment: @Alex, which punishments? The ones when they failed on the trip from Egypt? Or?

Comment: @gamliela Any, though the question mentions Eve and Cain as examples.

Comment: Kain is most interesting. To receive a letter, special sign, from G-d and go on to build cities, a sign of penance. It worked out well in a way.

Comment: @gamliela Some think that Cain was not given a special sign and exiled by G-d but, left of his own accord when he realized that his company was no longer welcomed. I do not think Eve's pain of childbirth and Adam tilling the land is a punishment. Additionally, these tasks are natural. They aren't punishments but natural consequences. There is no punishment because Eden will return in the messianic era. Original sin is not a Jewish concept, it is a Christian invention that crept into Judaism unchecked and must be eradicated from Jewish thought.

Comment: I do not think #3 is correct, as far as the forbidden fruit is concerned. I think Chava was punished for giving Adam the fruit, but not for eating it herself. This is the easiest way to read the text - God asked Adam if he ate the fruit, he said "the woman gave me some and I ate", and God told the woman, "since you did this" you will be punished.

Comment: Chava knew to tell the snake that she may not touch the tree, so it seems that Adam did tell her about the prohibition.

Comment: I'll construct an answer here in the comments. Throughout history, many people were made aware of the Noahide laws and didn't bother to keep them. If there were an 8th law called "chinuch habanim" it would have likewise been disregarded. Kayin recognized the enormity of his sin immediately after committing it and felt the need to be punished. Similar to the kabbalistic concept that the soul needs gehinom to absolve it of its feelings of guilt and shame. There is in general no indication that Heavenly punishment was a regular occurrence or indeed that it is today.

Comment: The Noahide laws were far more well-known post-mabul than many believe. Canaan merited the land of Israel because they had a moral lifestyle. Many were receptive to, and converted to, Abrahamism. Sodom was a notorious exception to the rule. Shechem was a notorious exception to this rule. As late as the Moshe's generation the Moabites are criticized for breaking the taboo on arayot see rashi bamidbar 22:5. Idol worship may have been common but nothing else really.

Comment: Bereishis 18:19

Comment: @Derdeer Sorry I don’t see where you actually address the question.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, if Adam was the only one informed about a commandment that others were obligated in, he would have an oblgation to share it with others who needed to follow the commandment. And indeed, that is what he did. While this is obvious and logical, there is at least one source that explicitly describes Adam's teaching of the commandment to Chavah.

It is clear from Chavah's response in [Bereshis 3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.3?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) that she was at least partially aware of some prohibition regarding the Tree of Knowledge. Indeed, part of what caused the error was due to being over-warned regarding the commandment. Chavah said to the snake that it is forbidden to touch the tree. However, when Hashem warned Adam about the tree, he was only told that it is forbidden to eat from the tree. Where did Chavah come up with the idea that touching is also forbidden?

When Adam informed Chavah of the prohibition, he added an additional safeguard to prevent transgression, by saying that even touching is forbidden. 
While this ended up backfiring, we see that Adam did indeed share the commandments that were told to him with Chavah.

This is recorded in [Avos D'Rabbi Nosson 1:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D'Rabbi_Natan.1?lang=bi) (only quoting the relevant middle of the Mishnah):

> איזהו סייג שעשה אדם הראשון לדבריו הרי הוא אומר (בראשית ב) ויצו ה׳
>   אלהים על האדם [לאמר] מכל עץ הגן אכול תאכל ומעץ הדעת טוב ורע לא תאכל
>   ממנו כי ביום אכלך ממנו מות תמות לא רצה אדם הראשון לומר לחוה כדרך שא״ל
>   הקב״ה אלא כך אמר לה ועשה סייג לדבריו יותר ממה שאמר לו הקב״ה ומפרי העץ
>   אשר בתוך הגן אמר אלהים לא תאכלו ממנו ולא תגעו בו פן תמותון שרצה לשמור
>   את עצמו ואת חוה מן העץ אפילו בנגיעה.
>
> What safeguard did First Man make for his words? The verse states:
>   (Gen. 2) "And YKVK God commanded man, saying, 'you may eat from all
>   the fruits of the garden; however from the tree (which provides)
>   knowledge of good and evil you may not eat, for the day on which you
>   will eat from it, you will surely die.' " First Man did not want to
>   tell this to Eve in the same manner God had told it to him, rather he
>   told her thus, making a safeguard for his words, (restrictive) to a
>   greater extent than what the Holy One, Blessed be He, told him:
>   (ibid.) "and concerning the fruit of the tree in (the center of) the
>   garden, God said 'do not eat of it and do not touch it, lest you die.'
>   " Because he wanted to guard himself and Eve from the tree - not even
>   to touch.

Comment: Thank you. If you notice, you start with minute detail and immediately expand it into an obvious generalization. 1. We do have traces of Eve's knowledge of the (only) commandment. This says nothing about the other 7, this says nothing about Adam teaching others, this says nothing about Adam being *obligated* to do so. 2. The Midrash only deals with the difference in the language, it does not deal straight with the question I ask. 3. How logical it is for G-d to command on something and forgot to command to pass it on?

Comment: @AlBerko No, you misunderstand my answer. The gist of my answer is the first paragraph: it is logical and obvious, therefore there is no need for the Torah to record it. Full stop. Everything else is just icing, the fact that there is an incident that shows Adam explicitly sharing a commandment is just a bonus.

Comment: This is a serious problem in religious reasoning - just like Rambam - G-d exists and this is obvious. And everything else that *you* think is logical and reasonable and obvious, but because I (or others) don't reach that spiritual level we simply can't see it. I heard it 25 years ago when they tried to make me Teshuva promising that if I learn I will reach that level of "obvious". That never came. 2. There are tons of obvious things in Torah, repetitions, unneeded words, etc. So if you don't have an answer, simply don't reply.

Answer (score -1):

It is understood from the creation of the sun and moon. They establish the paradigm that is later expressed via the creation of Adam and Chava. The sun shines on the moon, which then reflects the light received from the sun. The moon is a source of *reflected light.*

In the same way, Chava lost her direct memory of G-d's teachings when she was *built* from Adam HaRishon. At that point, she had to be taught by her husband what was expected of her. That's the main point of the sin of the Tree of Knowledge. Chava responded to the Nachash exactly what her husband had taught her. See [Siftei Chachamim to Bereshit 3:2 beginning with the words, "כיון שהיא ידעה בעצמה כו׳"](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=68) for details.

Comment: There is no mention of this episode in the Torah. Is this a derash?

Comment: @Jonathan Not following your question. Are you talking about the creation of the sun and moon, or the creation of Adam HaRishon and the building of Chava?

Comment: The story about Eve losing memory is not in the Torah. And Adam teaching her implies that women can't think on their own? That woman may forget important information on a whim?

Comment: @Jonathan Actually it is stated explicitly in Ikar Siftei Chachamim to Bereshit 3:2. The idea is discussed in Sefer HaGilgulim in relation to reincarnation. When a soul occupies a new body, the new body alters the memory related to that soul. Recollection of past existence is blocked from conscious memory. When Chava was 'built' from the cell of Adam HaRishon (akin to the concept of cloning) her memory, which was the identical memory of Adam HaRishon was blocked.

Comment: @Jonathan Con't: She had to be taught by her husband, reflecting his memory/light. Adam was the source for her. And her mistake was the consequence of him adding to G-d's commandment.

Comment: That thought is thought-provoking. I do not believe in reincarnation. Is this kabbalistic sourced? I also think Adam and Chava had a father and a mother like you and me. I am not alone in this thinking. Kabbalist, Rabbi Michael Laitman explains, "Adam was the first one who disclosed this power. This explains why he is called the First Man. Numerous people lived before him. Many generations elapsed before his birth. He was born of a father and mother like everyone else." See Josephus’s (Flavius) writings.

Comment: THank you. Eve is just an example of things going wrong. The later generations were severely punished, meaning G-d expected from them to follow His laws without commanding Adam or anybody else on kepassing them on. Don't you agree?

Comment: Eve doesn't do everything wrong. She gets somethings right. Don't be too harsh on her. Adam also ate from the fruit.

Comment: If this answer is based on Sigsei Chachamim or on other Midrashim, please add a reference in the answer.

Comment: @simyou The Siftei Chachamim isn't really a part of this answer. It's only to respond to Jonathan's question. But I will add a link for you.

Answer (score -2):

The possibilities are endless. We will go through a few (but of course not all) as to why Adam *seemingly* did not pass on the commandments.

(1) It is possible, that the Torah or Oral Torah [oral law] did not exist in the time of Adam. The seven Noahide commandments are a rabbinical invention. It is not in the Torah. No court existed in the days of Noah. This could account for Eve and Cain's mistakes.

(2) It is possible, and some think this is so, that the story of Cain is not a true story but a parable. I do not remember Maimonides explicitly saying this, but he did say in Guide 1:2 that the story of the Garden of Eden is a parable.

(3) If the above is not a parable, why is Cain punished for a sin he was told nothing about? Why do we not see Adam and Eve’s reaction to the murder? Is it possible that Cain only meant to hurt his brother but not kill him? Did G-d exile him or did he realize his mistake and left of his own?

(4) Yet another possibility is Kabbalistic. Accordingly, G-d gave [or Adam discovered] the Torah and followed them. But like the person who knowingly passes through a redlight, Eve, Cain, and Noah would have transgressed the law, purposely and intentionally.

(5) There is a Midrash that says that G-d gave the patriarchs the option of keeping [or observeing] the commandments [mitzvots]. They could choose to keep all of them, partially, or none at all. They did so only out of a love of G-d.

(6) The Rambam writes that Abraham did not keep the law. He only knew the philosophic aspects of Judaism. He discovered G-d by studying the heavens but did not observe all of the mitzvot. He later explains that this was the reason why most of the Israelites in Egypt forgot G-d and left for idol worship until Moshe led them out of slavery. He explains this as the reason to keep the mitzvot. If we fail to do the rituals, we may forget the philosophy. This would explain Adam's neglect of the law.

(7) The "Garden of Eden" story is a parable and needs no explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I think in general you miss the point of the question - Assuming G-d commanded Adam in the first place, why there’s no obligation of passing the commandments?

Comment: Whether Adam discovered the Torah or it was given, numerous things could have taken place. Perhaps Adam was not near Eve when she ate the fruit or she disobeyed him anyway. Pandora's box?

Comment: 1. Seems wrong - Rabbis claim Adam was commanded and all of his descendants. otherwise how do you explain the flood? 2. Stop saying everything is fairy tales. Even if it is a story it has to be consistent. 3. Reverse logic - because G-d is good and He punishes - of course they are worth being punished. 4. Exactly needs explanation how did they know they were obligated. 5. Irrelevant 6. The Gemmorah claims Avraham and all kept the 7 laws - why? 7. G-d punished generations before Avraham, so it is also irrelevant. 7. see #2

Comment: The Talmud says that the 7 laws were given to Noach. Avraham - being a non-Jew, would have kept these laws. But the additional 613 were optional. I think Chava ate the fruit because of human nature. If I tell you not to think of a purple elephant, you will think to yourself: purple elephant, purple elephant, purple elephant. Many myths have people disobeying the gods. An Aztec myth tells that the gods told people [after the flood] not to eat corn, and what do they do? They eat corn, punished, and turned into turkeys and fish.

Comment: I think the Garden of Eden story has a lesson though. But it is not a fairy tale. Also, how can G-d punish Cain if according to Rambam, G-d does not speak?

Comment: If the "Garden of Eden" story is a parable that means there is a stronger need for explanation, because the parable needs to be translatable into relevant concepts.

Comment: @simyou Who is right? Does G-d mete out reward and punishment in accordance with human deeds? Is this contentiously? The smartest man who ever lived, Albert Einstein certainly felt that reward and punishment were childish. But if it is real, why do the righteous suffer? Why the holocaust? Where was G-d in the holocaust? Why did so many nazis get away with their crimes, including Hitler who put a bullet into his brain.

Comment: Perhaps divine retribution is reserved for the World to Come? Indeed the very mystery of reward and punishment provides people with freedom of choice - free will. But if people were certain of the risk they run when acting out the evil inclination they would eschew evil, but not for good reasons but for fear of punishment. Can we judge Eve? Maybe the snake was placed in the garden intentionally.

Comment: I agree that there is a very strong explanation for the parable. See Rambam.

Comment: If the 7 laws were given to Noah what were his generation punished for?

Comment: What an excellent question. I think the 7 laws were given after the flood. But can we justify G-d’s decision to “blot out from the earth the men whom I created—man together with beasts, creeping things, and birds of the sky” (Genesis 6:7)? Do you think that every single person was bad, with no exceptions? Do you think that the animals, who only act according to their instincts, were bad? Why were they killed?

Comment: Is it really possible for the entire world, with the exception of one family, to become so totally corrupt and evil that it is worthy of obliteration? Could the Bible be exaggerating to make a point? Is it possible that the entire world was not flooded, but just a single area?